# NSSM - wrong time in log file

Tags: nssm

I'm using NSSM to start my application, all fine.
But the logging timestamp in the file is exact one hour behind my system time like

2024-01-15 08:32:03.770: but it's already 2024-01-15 09:32:03 at my system where the service is running.
I'm working on windows machines.
I just have activated the timestamp logging with: %NSSM% set %SHORTNAME_MANAGER% AppTimestampLog 1

So my question is, if this problems is a known problem or if I can or have to configure something regarding timezones?

Using NSSM 2.24.

Thanks in advance.

I did just the setting like its described in the documentation:
%NSSM% set %SHORTNAME_MANAGER% AppTimestampLog 1